# Two seekbars forming an L?

Tags: android, seekbar

I am a newbie in Android and may not know all the options. Any help is appreciated.

What is the right way of specifying "% of screen width" and "% of screen length"? Which is the right type of the layout?

I am trying to make one vertical in left 20% of the screen and one horizontal seekbar in bottom 20% of the screen with with an image in the rest 80%-80% quadrant formed by them.

For sure, the following doesn't serve the purpose because the seekbars come steadfast in the middle:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:stretchColumns="*"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_title"/>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:progress="25" />

<ImageView />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:progress="50"
    android:rotation="270" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help get you on the right track. For what ever reason, android isn't turning the width and height attributes with the rotation, so it is only turning the view. So if you change the width of the vertical seekbar, it will get smaller as if it was still horizontal. I'm sure someone has a better way or a way to fix this, but i can't spend much more time on this right now. Later i might, and i'll check it then, but for now this works-ish.

I included an image of what i have. The highlighted blue is the image view.

The dimensions are based on a nexus 5 1080x1776 (not including the thing at the top that has the time and notifications).

**Edit:**

Usually, you don't use X% for width and height. I use pixels because I design for specific devices, such as the Nexus 5. I think the normal width and height that isn't the wrap, match, or fill, is the em? Or dp? It's something like that. Someone else could tell you, or you could look it up.

You picked the correct layout. A Relative layout as it was described to me, is the placement of the views relative to the others. It's placed anywhere, basically. And a linear layout is stacked. Each view will follow the other.

[image: vertical seekbar]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Here"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="335.2px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:progress="25" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:progress="50"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="864px"
        android:layout_height="1420.8px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```